# spinner list is not displaying in android

Tags: android, layout

Hi in the below code fetching all the building details from API's .After getting the response from the server and then I am adding to the spinner.

In the below code want to display names of the building want to display in spinner.
below response want to display all the names in spinner list.

can any one help me where I did the mistake.

Response from server:

```
  {
        "list": [
            {
                "ID": "6",
                "Name": "Microsoft1"
            },
            {
                "ID": "9",
                "Name": "building6567"
            }
        ]
    }



private void selectBuilding() {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Write code for your refresh logic

                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog (getActivity ());
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Communicating...");
                progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build();

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(API.URL_BASE)
                        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .client (client)
                        .build();
                API service = retrofit.create (API.class);
                final Call<Managebuilding> userCall = service.getbuildinglist ();
                userCall.enqueue(new Callback<Managebuilding> () {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call <Managebuilding> call, Response <Managebuilding> response) {

                        if (response != null && response.code ( ) == 200 && response.isSuccessful ( )) {
                            Managebuilding building = response.body ();
                            arrayList = new ArrayList <> ( );
                            arrayList.addAll(building.getList());

                            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext (), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, building.getList());///error 

                            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

                            /** Adding radio buttons for the spinner items */
                            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                            progressDialog.dismiss ( );

                        } else {
                            progressDialog.dismiss ( );
                            Log.d ("Response errorBody", String.valueOf (response.errorBody ( )));
                        }

                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Managebuilding> call, Throwable t) {
                        // lv.setAdapter (adapter);
                        System.out.println("onFailure");
                        System.out.println(t.fillInStackTrace());
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity (), "Some error occurred -> ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
                        // progressDialog.dismiss();



                    }

                });
            }


        }, 5000);
        return ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a pojo class

```
public class SpinnerUtils {
     public SpinnerUtils(String spinnerText, int value) {
         this.spinnerText = spinnerText;
         this.value = value;
     }

     public String getSpinnerText() {
         return spinnerText;
     }

     public int getValue() {
         return value;
     }

     public String toString() {
         return spinnerText;
     }

     String spinnerText;
     int value;
 }
```

Then

```
SpinnerUtils items[]=new SpinnerUtils[array.length()];
    items[i] = new SpinnerUtils(c.getString("name"), c.getInt("id"));   

    for (int i = 0; i <array.length(); i++) {

items[i] = new SpinnerUtils(c.getString("name"), c.getInt("id"));                       
                }


         ArrayAdapter<SpinnerUtils> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<SpinnerUtils>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                s.setAdapter(adapter);
```

where s is your spinner and array is the JSONArray retrieved from API. To retrieve the id:

```
 SpinnerUtils d = items[position];
             int   standard = d.getValue();
```

Create the above 2 lines within the setOnItemSelectedListener of the spinner to get the id.Hope it will work.

Comment: Y are you created new pojo class